# i cannot fix "Uncaught TypeError: D.Buttons is undefined" when add export button in server side dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

i got error on my console browser , it happen when i wanna add export button in dataTable server side. i have been import all required js library to my header .

this is my error at browser console :

> Uncaught TypeError: D.Buttons is undefined

at buttons.html5.min.js:11:425

and

> Uncaught TypeError: w.Buttons is undefined

at buttons.flash.min.js:31:1

my generate datatable report function :

```
 // Generate DataTable Function
  window.generateDataTable = function (selector, ajax, data = null, columns, pageLength = 5, createdRow = null, btnExport = null, buttons = null) {
    let ajaxParams = {
      url: ajax,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + sessionGetter.token
      },
    }
    data !== null ? ajaxParams.data = data : false
    selector.DataTable({
      autoWidth: false,
      lengthChange: false,
      retrieve: true,
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copy','csv','print', 'excel', 'pdf'
      ],
      pageLength: pageLength,
      language: {
        info: '',
        infoFiltered: "filter dari _MAX_ total data"
      },
      ajax: ajaxParams,
      columns: columns,
      columnDefs: [{
        targets: '_all',
        createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData) {
          $(td).addClass('align-middle text-center')
        },
      }],
      createdRow: createdRow,

    }).draw()
  }
```

My header :

```
    <!-- DataTable -->
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $url ?>/component/assets/vendor/DataTables/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

if you get something missing and wrong please tell me . i really confuse about this issue

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when was trying to repeat this demo https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html.
The problem disappears if place import of `dataTables.buttons.min.js` before `buttons.html5.min.js`.

This is a working example for that tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```